# How to move only files that contains specific text from one Google bucket to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell, google-bucket

I want to use Google cloud shell to move files that contain a specific text to another bucket.
There are more than 10K files in the bucket so I can't do it manually by the interface.
Please advise how to deal with this issue. [image]

Comment: You cannot query by the content of the objects, you may need to download and check every file

Comment: You have to read all files... Depending on your requirements and context - a dataflow https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/  might be an option to use for development. If files are small - another option - a cloud function https://cloud.google.com/functions/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments by [@Ferregina Pelona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12265927/ferregina-pelona) & [@al-dann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6073141/al-dann), At the moment Google `Cloud Storage` **does not** support this kind of file/s processing (i.e. you can't operate over file/s content).

You will have to use any of the available compute services like `GCE`, `GKE`, `Cloud Functions`, `Dataflow`, `Cloud Composer`, etc.